# spring boot (mvc) response with different content type encoding on error

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, error-handling, spring-boot

I need help with spring handling an error.

a client service is sending a request accepting two different content types - binary and json. when everything works fine I prefer communicating to my server with binary encoding to save bandwidth. but on error I would like serialise ResponseEntity to json as my binary serialiser do not know how to serialise it to binary format, plus it is better for logging, etc.

I configured instance of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and I am handling different exceptions from that implementation. but spring always choses binary format as it is first on the accept (or produces) list.

all I get is (because spring do not know how to serialise ResponseEntity to my custom binary format. see AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor#writeWithMessageConverters)

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

client sends

```
headers {Accept: [application/custom-binary, application/json]
```

server's controller is configured to

```
// pseudo code
@RequestMapping(method = GET, produces = {"application/custom-binary", APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public BannerMetaCollection get(@RequestParam(value = "q") UUID[] q) {
    if (q != null) {
        return service.getAllDataWith(q);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid data");
    }
}

// pseudo code
public class RestExceptionResolverSupport extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<Object> illegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException ex, WebRequest request {
        Object body = errorResponse()
                    .withCode(BAD_REQUEST)
                    .withDescription("Request sent is invalid")
                    .withMessage(ex.getMessage())
                    .build());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(body, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do to get this to work is that a let my endpoint method return a `ResponseEntity` and I don't declare what content is produced in the `@RequestMapping` annotation. I then set the Content-type header myself before returning the response, e.g.

```
// pseudo code
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<BannerMetaCollection> get(@RequestParam(value = "q") UUID[] q) {
    if (q != null) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/custom-binary");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getAllDataWith(q),
                headers,
                HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid data");
    }
}
```